# Powershell script called from C does not open OleDb Connection

Tags: c, powershell, oledb, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

When calling a `Powershell` script from a `C` function, my database connection does not open.  However when I log on to the server as the user that runs the `C` program and launch it from a DOS prompt, everything works as expected.

Why would the `C` program not be able to open the database connection via `C`.

The server is Windows 2008 R2 64-bit.

Here is the `Powershell` script Im running.  It creates a debug log for me to validate which parts are working.

```
$DEBUGStream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "D:\powershell\DEBUG.txt"
$DEBUGStream.WriteLine("START DEBUG")

$ExcelFile = "D:\InterfaceData\excel\" + $args[0]
$Sheetname = "Sheet2$"
$OleDbConn = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection”
$OleDbCmd = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand”
$OleDbAdapter = New-Object “System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter”
$DataTable = New-Object “System.Data.DataTable”

$OleDbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$ExcelFile`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES`";"
$OleDbConn.Open()

$DEBUGStream.WriteLine("Connection: $OleDbConn.State")
    $DEBUGStream.WriteLine("Environment: $env:Processor_Architecture")

$OleDbCmd.Connection = $OleDbConn
$OleDbCmd.commandtext = “Select * from [$Sheetname]”
$OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $OleDbCmd

$RowsReturned = $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable)
$DEBUGStream.WriteLine("Data Table fill: Rows: $RowsReturned")
$intRow = 1
ForEach ($DataRec in $DataTable) {
    $DEBUGStream.WriteLine("DATA TABLE ROW $intRow")
    $intRow++
}

$DEBUGStream.WriteLine("Loop finished")

$OleDbConn.Close()

$DEBUGStream.WriteLine("All Closed")
$DEBUGStream.close()
```

Here is the output when I run in manually from DOS prompt

```
C:\Users\me>powershell -executionpolicy bypass d:\powershell\Interface.ps1 test.xlsx
START DEBUG
Connection: Open
    Environment: AMD64
Data Table fill: Rows: 4
DATA TABLE ROW 1
DATA TABLE ROW 2
DATA TABLE ROW 3
DATA TABLE ROW 4
Loop finished
All Closed
```

Here is the output when it gets called from the `C` program.  I call it using the `system` command.

```
START DEBUG
Connection: Closed
    Environment: x86
Data Table fill: Rows: 
Loop finished
All Closed
```

---

**EDIT**

If I run the 64-bit `Powershell` version and run the script from a command prompt I get a new error.  I have installed the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (14.0.4763.1000):

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass d:\wcc_powershell\WRIRMPTruckInterface.ps1 test.xlsx

C:\Users\me>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass d:\powershell\Interface.ps1 
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
At D:\powershell\Interface.ps1:19 char:16
+ $OleDbConn.Open <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: There is no DOS prompt - DOS has been dead for over a decade. There are 2 possible command-line environments in 2K8R2 - CMD & PowerShell. Which are you using?

Comment: @alroc - When I run it on the server, straight from Powershell, I open a command prompt and run the command `powershell -executionpolicy bypass d:\powershell\Interface.ps1 test.xlsx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute it from the "C" program, you can clearly see it launches as a 32 bit process (x86). Since you don't have the 32 bit OleDb drivers installed, this is the issue at hand. You need to compile the "C" program as a 64 bit PE and then it will launch powershell as a 64 bit process. Alternatively, execute powershell explictly with the following path:

`c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

This will force the 32 bit "C" program to launch powershell as a 64 bit child process.

Here's a related blog post of mine: http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2012/12/18/Ensuring-a-PowerShell-script-will-always-run-in-a-64-bit-shell

Comment: Exactly right!  I found [this blog entry](http://cornasdf.blogspot.com/2009/09/force-powershell-script-to-run-in-x86.html) about forcing powershell to detect if its running 32-bit powershell on a 64-bit architecture.  So the script will automatically run itself in the proper process.

Comment: I updated the answer with link to a recent blog post of mine on the subject.